# Determing Smallest Number With Methods/Arrays/Private Values

Tags: c#, methods

Hello I am a first year college student and I am learning C#

My question is regarding methods and determining the smallest number of x numbers when the values required are private

So to be more exact I am working on code and the user can enter as many pets as they want/have and I will gather the information Name/Age/Breed/ But I am having trouble with determining the youngest/smallest age. Since I cannot directly assign pets[0].Age > pets[i].Age of the class since it is private.

Apologies if this is a poorly phrased question but I hope I explained it well enough for you to understand and answer.

### CODE

```
        int totalPets;
        System.Console.WriteLine("How many pets do you own?");
        totalPets = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine()

        Pet[] pets;
        pets = new Pet[totalPets];

        int small;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalPets; i++)
        {
            pets[i] = new Pet();
            pets[i].GetPetName();
            pets[i].GetPetAge();
            pets[i].GetPetBreed();
            pets[i].PrintPetInfo();
        }

        pets[0].AssignSmall();

        for(int i = 0; i < totalPets; i++)
        {
            if(pets[0].AssignSmall < )
        }
```

### CLASS CODE

```
    internal class Pet
    private string Name;
    public string GetPetName()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("What is your dogs name?");
        Name = System.Console.ReadLine();
        return Name;
    }
    private int Age;
    public int GetPetAge()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("What is your dogs age?");
        return this.Age = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
    }
    private string Breed;
    public string GetPetBreed()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("What is your dogs breed?");
        return this.Breed = System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public void PrintPetInfo()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(this.Name + " is " + this.Age + " and is a " + Breed);
    }

    public int AssignSmall()
    {
        int small;
        small = this.Age;
        return small;
        
    }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will answer your question. I'm going to make some observations about your code:

- GetPetName should not ask for the name, just return it. Maybe AskForName would be a better name. Right now it is not possible to get the name without asking the user for it first. Personally, I would put the data retrieval outside the class because depending on the case it could be possible to get it from a database, a file, a Web service, the user... and creating different methods inside the class makes the class itself (the business model) to be coupled with the data retrieval (infrastructure).
- If GetPetName is limited to return the name, it is often interesting to use a property.
- The property should also have a set to be able to set its value. It does not make much sense that intrinsic properties of the object cannot be queried/set. How do you work with a Pet if you cannot access its properties? What is the use of the class then?

So your class could be something like this:

```
public class Pet
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
}
```

Very simple. In normal developments, classes are more complex and have methods to do something with the class properties, but with your sample, this is my personal implementation.

We can use a method to ask user for one Pet data:

```
private static Pet AskUserForPet()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("What is your dogs name?");
    var name = System.Console.ReadLine();

    int age = 0;
    var valid = false;
    while (!valid)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("What is your dogs age?");
        valid = int.TryParse(System.Console.ReadLine(), out age);
    }

    System.Console.WriteLine("What is your dogs breed?");
    var breed = System.Console.ReadLine();

    return new Pet
    {
        Name = name,
        Age = age,
        Breed = breed
    };
}
```

That method maybe in your Program.cs, not in the class. In bigger projects, that kind of things are made in the Infrastructure layer.

And for the creation of your pets:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("How many pets do you own?");
var totalPets = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

Pet[] pets = new Pet[totalPets];

for (int i = 0; i < totalPets; i++)
{
    pets[i] = AskUserForPet();

    System.Console.WriteLine(pets[i].Name + " is " + pets[i].Age + " and is a " + pets[i].Breed);
}
```

You can use previous code to get the youngest pet:

```
Pet youngestPet = null;
Pet[] pets = new Pet[totalPets];

for (int i = 0; i < totalPets; i++)
{
    pets[i] = AskUserForPet();

    System.Console.WriteLine(pets[i].Name + " is " + pets[i].Age + " and is a " + pets[i].Breed);

    if (youngestPet == null || pets[i].Age < youngestPet.Age)
    {
        youngestPet = pets[i];
    }
}
```

Or, if you need do it later:

```
Pet youngestPet = null;
for (int i = 0; i < pets.Length; i++)
{
    if (youngestPet == null || pets[i].Age < youngestPet.Age)
    {
        youngestPet = pets[i];
    }
}
```

Using LINQ you can simplify the code:

```
var youngestPet = pets.Aggregate((youngest, x) => 
    youngest == null || x.Age < youngest.Age ? x : youngest);
```

Comment: Yes that would definitely be much more effective but the project rules that I have to abide by are all of the member variables must be private. So I cannot refer to pets.Age directly in the main program. That is the problem im running into primarily.